# Azure CLI - List all subscriptions with tags

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I need to list all subscriptions with:

Sub name, Sub ID, Status, Tags, Parent Management Group

I tried using:

```
az graph query -q "resourcecontainers | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions' | project id, name, subscriptionId, tags"
```

But it does not seem to have an option to list state or Management Group.

Is there a way list all of those properties at once?

Comment: To list all subscriptions with Sub name, Sub ID, Status, Tags, and Parent Management Group using Azure CLI, you can use the following query:

`az graph query -q "Resources | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions' | extend managementGroup = tostring(properties.managementGroup) | project id, name, subscriptionId, tags, provisioningState, managementGroup"`
This query uses the Resources table instead of ResourceContainers to include the provisioningState and managementGroup properties.

Comment: @Arko It seems like **provisioningState** does not work as im getting an error: 
`"code": "Operator_FailedToResolveEntity","message": "'project' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'provisioningState'"`
and without it i get no results at all

Comment: For the subscriptions' information (Sub name, Sub ID, Tags), you can use the following query:

   ` az graph query -q "resourcecontainers | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions' | project id, name, subscriptionId, tags"`

[output here](https://i.imgur.com/lUkTX0v.png)

Comment: For the `Status`, if you're referring to the state of the subscription (like Enabled, Disabled, etc.), this is not directly available in the Azure Resource Graph. You may need to use Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI to list the state separately. The Azure CLI command `az account list --query "[].{name:name, state:state}"` can give you the name and state. [output here](https://i.imgur.com/DQfDYgm.png)

Comment: did the above command work for you as shown in the output?

Comment: Command works, I need to connect it to the rest of the properties from az graph query

Comment: Good to know. Can I post this as answer then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the list of all subscriptions with the Sub name, Sub ID, Tags, and Parent Management Group, you would typically need to combine data from multiple commands or queries since this information might not be available in a single query.

For the subscriptions' information (Sub name, Sub ID, Tags), you can use the following query:

```
az graph query -q "resourcecontainers | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions' | project id, name, subscriptionId, tags"
```

[image]
For the `Status`, if you're referring to the state of the subscription (like Enabled, Disabled, etc.), this is not directly available in the Azure Resource Graph. You may need to use Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI to list the state separately. The Azure CLI command `az account list --query "[].{name:name, state:state}"` can give you the name and state.
[image: output here]

If you need to combine this information, you might have to write a script that uses the output of multiple commands to create a consolidated view.

References:

- [Azure Resource Graph sample queries for management groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/resource-graph-samples#sample-queries)
- [Azure Resource Graph sample queries by category](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/samples/samples-by-category#management-groups)